# USB-C 3.x port running at 2.0 speeds

Tags: usb, usb-c

I noticed that every device I plugged in to the USB-C port on my computer (which is USB 3.1 or, should I say, 3.2 Gen. 2 - WTF those names), it only runs at 2.0 speeds (480Mbps). After doing some troubleshooting, here's what I discovered:

If I shut down my machine, plug my USB 3 device in to the USB-C port, power it on and let the OS boots... it works at 3.x speeds just fine until I plug it off; if I unplug and plug RIGHT IMMEDIATELLY the exact same USB 3 device at the exact same USB-C port at the exact same orientation, it starts to run at 2.0 speeds.

Logs:

```
$ lsmod | grep xhci
xhci_pci               24576  0
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci

$ lsusb -tvv (Device Plugged at Boot)
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb4  /dev/bus/usb/004/001
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
        ID 0bc2:ab24 Seagate RSS LLC Backup Plus Portable Drive
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-2  /dev/bus/usb/004/002
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3  /dev/bus/usb/003/001
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        ID 0d8c:0267 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4  /dev/bus/usb/003/002
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        ID 0d8c:0267 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4  /dev/bus/usb/003/002
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        ID 0d8c:0267 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4  /dev/bus/usb/003/002
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        ID 0d8c:0267 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4  /dev/bus/usb/003/002
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 04f2:b729 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-7  /dev/bus/usb/003/003
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 04f2:b729 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-7  /dev/bus/usb/003/003
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 480M
        ID 04f2:b729 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-7  /dev/bus/usb/003/003
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-10  /dev/bus/usb/003/004
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-10  /dev/bus/usb/003/004
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2  /dev/bus/usb/002/001
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1  /dev/bus/usb/001/001

$ lsusb -tvv (Device Plugged After)
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb4  /dev/bus/usb/004/001
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3  /dev/bus/usb/003/001
    |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 480M
        ID 0bc2:ab24 Seagate RSS LLC Backup Plus Portable Drive
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2  /dev/bus/usb/003/005
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        ID 0d8c:0267 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4  /dev/bus/usb/003/002
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        ID 0d8c:0267 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4  /dev/bus/usb/003/002
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        ID 0d8c:0267 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4  /dev/bus/usb/003/002
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        ID 0d8c:0267 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4  /dev/bus/usb/003/002
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 04f2:b729 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-7  /dev/bus/usb/003/003
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 04f2:b729 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-7  /dev/bus/usb/003/003
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 480M
        ID 04f2:b729 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-7  /dev/bus/usb/003/003
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-10  /dev/bus/usb/003/004
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-10  /dev/bus/usb/003/004
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2  /dev/bus/usb/002/001
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1  /dev/bus/usb/001/001

# dmesg | grep usb
[    0.410409] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.410409] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.410409] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.037286] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.037289] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.037290] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.037299] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-48-lowlatency xhci-hcd
[    1.037300] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:0d.0
[    1.038444] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.038446] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.038447] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.038447] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-48-lowlatency xhci-hcd
[    1.038448] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:0d.0
[    1.056570] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.056573] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.056577] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.056580] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-48-lowlatency xhci-hcd
[    1.056581] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.060968] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.060970] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.060971] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.060972] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-48-lowlatency xhci-hcd
[    1.060973] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.386622] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.401860] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab24, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    1.404376] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[    1.406798] usb 4-2: Product: BUP Slim BK
[    1.409239] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[    1.411688] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: *** REDACTED ***
[    1.421629] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.516373] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.545216] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    1.658002] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0d8c, idProduct=0267, bcdDevice= 3.03
[    1.660634] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.663081] usb 3-4: Product: USB Advanced Audio Device
[    1.665707] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: C-Media Electronics Inc.
[    1.784365] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.915009] usb 3-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b729, bcdDevice=27.39
[    1.918029] usb 3-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    1.920695] usb 3-7: Product: Chicony USB2.0 Camera
[    1.922273] usb 3-7: Manufacturer: CHICONY
[    1.923719] usb 3-7: SerialNumber: *** REDACTED ***
[    2.041402] usb 3-10: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.173118] usb 3-10: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0029, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    2.176007] usb 3-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.191332] input: C-Media Electronics Inc. USB Advanced Audio Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.3/0003:0D8C:0267.0002/input/input9
[    2.245781] hid-generic 0003:0D8C:0267.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [C-Media Electronics Inc. USB Advanced Audio Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input3
[    2.248777] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.251559] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    4.934341] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    4.965728] usb 3-7: Found UVC 1.10 device Chicony USB2.0 Camera (04f2:b729)
[    4.993479] input: Chicony USB2.0 Camera: Chicony  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/input/input16
[    5.007011] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    5.233342] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio

--- AFTER UNPLUGGING AND PLUGGING IT BACK ---

[  115.162502] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  132.104663] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  132.233494] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab24, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  132.233502] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  132.233505] usb 3-2: Product: BUP Slim BK
[  132.233508] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  132.233510] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: *** REDACTED ***
```

This happens only with the USB-C port, the USB-A 3.x works perfectly all the time.

Some forums suggested adding `iommu=soft` parameter on my boot entry, no changes; others suggested turning off `Legacy USB support` at UEFI/BIOS Menu but that option doesn't exist on my machine.

My machine is a Clevo NJ70MU laptop, OS is Ubuntu MATE 22.04.1 but I made the same test with a LiveUSB running Ubuntu (vanilla) 22.04.1, Debian 11.0.5 and Arch (2022.09.03) ISOs, the results are exactly the same.

Any ideas or advice on how to fix that?

Comment: Filed a bug report on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-lowlatency/+bug/1991028

Comment: UPDATE: It's a hardware bug on my laptop. I installed Windows in a separate disk on my own machine, the same thing occured; I ran the same tests on the other USB-C equipped machines at home and they work just fine. Now, I'm contacting the manufacturer to see what they say about it and, maybe, they provide some sort of fix.

Comment: UPDATE #2: It isn't just me, I found this post on Reddit ( https://www.reddit.com/r/Clevo/comments/dh5o9h/issue_with_usb_31_typec_port_on_sager_np7856 ) reporting the same thing in a completely different model, 03 years ago